# Dynamoose - Get table data count

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-dynamodb

How do you count as like mysql "select count(*) from tablename" , in DynamoDB using the dynamoose node module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent available in DynamoDB. However, one workaround would be to get the `ItemCount` using describe table API.

**Drawback of ItemCount:-**

> DynamoDB updates this value approximately every six hours. Recent
>   changes might not be reflected in this value.

**Code to get item count of Movies table from local DynamoDB instance:-**

```
'use strict';
var dynamoose = require('dynamoose');
dynamoose.AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId : 'AKID',
    secretAccessKey : 'SECRET',
    region : 'us-east-1'
});
dynamoose.local();

var Schema = dynamoose.Schema;
var Table = dynamoose.Table;

var table = new Table('Movies', null, null, dynamoose);

table.describe(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));

    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        console.log("Number of item =====>", JSON.stringify(data.Table.ItemCount, null, 2));
    }
});
```

**Output:-**

```
Number of item =====> 24
```